# How to create additional base fields for ECK entity

Tags: 8, entities

For example I want to create a `Vehicle` [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) base type and `Car` and `Truck` bundles, but I want to define fields for the `Vehicle` base type that would be shared between `Car` and `Truck`.

In UI, by default, I'm limited to this

[image]

I want to create more fields and use them in this form

Comment: I think you would want to add them as bundle fields rather than base fields. My subjective opinion is that ECK is terrible and you should never use it when architecting a site. It's better to define your own entity types in a custom module (drupal console can scaffold them for the lazy/slow typists).

Comment: @mradcliffe Yeah I can create field and then re-use it per bundle, but that seems kinda... meh (considering that ECK already has base fields to start wtih, so why not define my own). I agree that it might be better to define my own entity types in modules, but ECK seemed pretty straightforward and it's not that terrible (for now).